# Validation error messages not showing in form view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, simple-form

I have a simple model :

```
class Property < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :user
 has_many :invoices, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :tenants, dependent: :destroy

 validates :street, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50}
 validates :city, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50}
 validates :zip, presence: true, length: { maximum: 10}
 validates :rent, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50}


 def receivable
  (self.rent.to_i + self.charges.to_i)
  end
end
```

When trying in the console, the validation errors come as expected:

```
[2] pry(main)> prop = Property.new(street:"zzz")
 => #<Property:0x007fb99cde1cc0 id: nil, number: nil, streetype: nil, street: 
 "zzz", city: nil, zip: nil, rent: nil, charges: nil, user_id: nil, created_at: 
 nil, updated_at: nil>

[3] pry(main)> prop.save
(0.3ms)  BEGIN
(0.8ms)  ROLLBACK
=> false

[4] pry(main)> prop.errors.full_messages
=> ["User must exist", "City can't be blank", "Zip can't be blank", "Rent can't 
be blank"]
```

Here is the controller:

```
def new
 @user =  current_user
 @property = @user.properties.build
end

def create
 @user =  current_user
 @property = @user.properties.create(property_params)
 @property.user_id = current_user.id
  if @property.save
   flash[:notice] = "Nouveau Bien créé !"
   redirect_to user_properties_path
  else
   redirect_to new_user_property_path
 end
end
```

And here is the form view:

```
<div class="container center">
 <div class="row white">
  <div">
   <h2>Nouveau bien</h2>
   <%= simple_form_for([@user, @property]) do |j| %>
    <%= j.input :number, label:"Numéro" %>
    <%= j.input :streetype, label: "Laisser vide si nécessaire", collection: [" 
    ","rue","boulevard","allée"] , prompt: "Choisir" %>
    <%= j.input :street, label:"Nom" %>
    <%= j.input :city, label:"Commune / Ville" %>
    <%= j.input :zip, label:"Code Postal" %>
    <%= j.input :rent, label:"Montant du Loyer" %>
    <%= j.input :charges, label:"Montant des charges" %>
    <br>
    <%= j.submit 'Créer', class: "form-control btn btn-info" %>
   <% end %>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

When omitting one of the fields on purpose, the controller redirect to the correct form viw but validation error messages are not present. They use to show up but they disapeared for some reason.

Any idea why?

Thank you!

Comment: instead of `redirect_to new_user_property_path` in `else` block, you should `render 'new'`

Comment: Hello kiddorails! yes it works. Do you know why by any chance? thanks

Comment: Please answer the question so I can credit you with it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of `redirect_to new_user_property_path` in `else` block, you should

```
render 'new'
```

Reason: `redirect` instructs the browser to make the new request, because of which you end up loosing the context of `@property` object with it's errors. It actually makes a fresh request to `new` action. `render` will continue with the current action (which is `create` in this case) and render the response in `new` view with `@property`, errors and previous form body.